# Vistas no encontradas en Laravel 5.2 a pesar de que si están mis archivos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

estoy desarollando una tienda en linea y la ando desarrollando en local, anteriormente subi mi proyecto sin la api de paypal a mi hosting y todo funcionaba correctamente, pero despues de implementar el api de paypal y borrar la cache para que funcionara y me conectara a paypal, en cuando lo subi y quise acceder a mi index solo me aparece que la vista nola encuentra pero como dije subi todos mis archivos la carpeta completa y aun asi solo em dice que la vista no la encuentra ¿alguien podria ayudarme o explicarme porqué sucedio? sin embargo en localhost no me aparece ningun error de eso todo funciona bien solo que cuando subo mi proyecto mediante filezilla a mi host me aparece error

[image: MIS RUTAS]

[image: Mi controlador]

[image: Mis vistas del index]
[image: Y solo se muestra asi]
[image: Y como dije a pesar de que mis archivos estan arriba solo em dice que no encuentra la vista]

Y los mismo me pasa para cualquier otra ruta que meta me deice que no encuentra su vista correspondiente

Comment: saludos, prueba desde la consola limpiar la configuración y la cache de este modo y nos comentas php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear además un consejo trata de seguir las convenciones de nombres de Laravel pues los controladores deben seguir este orden por ejemplo UsuarioController

Comment: saludos Alfredo, entonces ejecuto esos comandos en CMD desde mi proyecto local? y vuelvo a subir mi carpeta? o como ingreso esos comandos, disculpa la ignorancia

Comment: no te apures, mira la idea es ejecutar estos comandos desde el CMD dentro de tu proyecto y volver a probarlo; no lo subas de nuevo si ya esta en producción a menos que si te sirvan

Comment: disculpa nuevamente pero a que te refieres con que este en producción? es que bueno todo lo hago en localhost y subo los archivos que edito al hosting, y en este caso volvi a subir toda la carpeta porque edite varios archivos, pero a que te refieres con que este en produccion?

Comment: producción es que ya esta montado en tu hosting, para acabar pronto me refiero a que hagas tus pruebas en tu localhost

Comment: Ok muchas gracias @Alfredo lo intentare de nuevo, muchhas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si puedes acceder al panel(cpanel) del hosting, intenta subir desde el administrador de archivos del hosting todo tu proyecto comprimido, **sin incluir el .env**, por si de pronto el error se te esta generando a causa de algún error al transmitir los archivos por ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Me da la impresión de que al subirla estás haciendo algo mal con la estructura de directorios.

La carpeta views que muestras en la imagen, debería estar dentro de la carpeta resources en la raíz del proyecto, ¿Es así?.

De no estar ahí eso explicaría por qué no te carga ninguna ruta.

> raíz -> resources -> views -> index.blade.php